# Asymptotic behavior of Fourier transform of $\exp(-x^4)$ at large $k$

Tags: special-functions, fourier-analysis

I am computing the Fourier transform

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,e^{-x^4+ikx}$$

for large $k$. Since $e^{-x^4}$ is $C^{\infty}$ on the whole real line, I expect its Fourier transform to decay faster than any power of $k$ at infinity. Indeed, with a saddle point approximation I find that the leading behavior is $\sim e^{-k^{4/3}}\times k^{-1/3}$ for large positive $k$.

*Mathematica* can do the integral in a closed form:

```
f[k_] = FourierTransform[Exp[-x^4], x, k]
```

returns

```
(* (2 Gamma[5/4] HypergeometricPFQ[{}, {1/2, 3/4}, k^4/256] -
    1/4 k^2 Gamma[3/4] HypergeometricPFQ[{}, {5/4, 3/2}, k^4/256])/Sqrt[2 π] *)
```

However, expanding this around $+\infty$ with

```
Series[f[k], {k, Infinity, 1}]
```

shows a leading behavior of $e^{k^{4/3}}\times k^{-1/3}$. Plotting the function $f(k)$ with *Mathematica* at large $k$ also shows a divergent result.

I am confused about this. I would expect the Fourier transform to be convergent at $k\to +\infty$, for the reasons explained above.

**UPDATE**

After fixing a mistake in the saddle point approximation, from the analytic calculation I get $f(k) = 0$ at large $k$. There is a cancellation between the contributions of two saddle points (each of which showed a behavior $\sim e^{-k^{4/3}}\times k^{-1/3}$, in any case).

Comment: When I plot the answer you get for f[k] I see it decays exponentially as k goes to infinity. The asymptotic expansion answer is suspect since there is likely an essential singularity at $k = \infty$, but the expression f[k] looks correct and has the correct (numerical) asymptotic behavior.

Comment: Until `k = 20` I also get a decay when I plot the function. But if I plot up to, e.g., `k = 40` the function `f[k]` seems to oscillate and diverge. I guess that it is just a numerical problem, and _Mathematica_'s closed form answer is correct.

Comment: the correct asymptotics is given at https://mathoverflow.net/q/366816/11260

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Landau-O-notation $\operatorname{O}((1/k)^\alpha)$ for $k \to \infty$ 
in Mathematica has to be taken with a grain of salt. It just tells us that Mathematica stopped the expansion at some point.

In this case it might be better to read it as: Something decays at *least* as fast as $(1/k)^{\alpha}$ without a statement on the sharpness of this estimate. 
Do higher order Laurent expansion and `Simplify` to highlight that. Just try

```
Series[f[k], {k, Infinity, 10}] // Simplify
Series[f[k], {k, Infinity, 20}] // Simplify
```

etc.

Comment: Expanding to higher order with `Series` still gives the overall factor of $e^{k^{4/3}}$. This will still diverge very fast at infinity whatever is the $(1/k)^n$ factor from the Laurent expansion.

Comment: Not if you never hit a nonzero coefficient... The function you are expanding might not be meromorphic at $\infty$ so that it might _not_ coincide with its Laurant series... Consider the Taylor expansion of $x \mapsto \exp(-x^{-2})$ at $x = 0$ for real $x$. The Taylor/Laurant expansion is all zero. The function ist not zero. The problem is that $\exp(1/z)$ has an _essential sigularity_ at $z=0$.

Comment: Just to understand better your point: do you think that it is correct to say that $f(k)$ should decay at infinity? I thought it should be true because the original function I am Fourier transforming is $C^{\infty}$.

Comment: Thinking of it: The result of generated be `FourierTransform` is weird indeed, as you essentially apply it to the squared of a Gauss bell. The result should be something like a Gauss bell convoluted with itself -- being again essentially a Gauss bell.

Comment: I don't think it's the square of a Gaussian: this would give $e^{-2x^2}$, not $e^{-x^4}$.

Comment: Ok, this is why I am confused by the result of _Mathematica_: even just using `Plot`(forgetting about `Series`) shows that the result diverges at large $k$.

Comment: The original function is a Schwartz function ($C^\infty$ with all derivatives decaying rapidly). So its Fourier transform is. Yes, you are right in that respect. And yes, it is not the square of a Gauss bell.